# How could I match the surrounding traffics displayed with their radio communication

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, ads-b, tcas

If I have a traffic display I could see the traffics in proximity of my aircraft and meanwhile I could listen to their voice communication. So how could I match the traffic shown in the display with the corresponding voice communication? My understanding is that if I have a ADS B in system and the other aircrafts have mode-s transponder, I could know their call sign thru the ADS-B data, is that right? But how about I just have a TCAS or I have the ADS-B in transponder but other aircrafts do not have a Mode-S transponder?

Comment: IANAP, but shouldn't _all_ radio communication start with `<who I am>` and `<who I'm talking to>` (maybe in the other order)? If you hear someone say `N12345 on approach runway 17L`, you should be able to correlate `N12345` with the appropriately labeled blip on your traffic display, no?

Comment: I could correlate N12345 to the traffic on my display who is indicated as approaching RW17L, but I can not be 100% sure, right? N12345 could be a aircraft without transponder, that is not shown on my traffic display or I have 2 traffics displayed as on the approach and I still can not tell which one is N12345, please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several approaches, currently impractical for GA:

- Your radio receiver would need to be directional, to estimate the
  sender's bearing and maybe distance, and from that derive the
  sender's identity.
- Voice broadcasts would need to be augmented with a digital squawk
  indicating the sender's call sign, like some automated speech
  broadcast weather reports do.
- Onboard [automatic speech
  recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition#Training_air_traffic_controllers)
  trained particularly for call signs could try to infer the sender's.

But we're a long way from duplicating how videoconfering software highlights whoever's speaking.